# how can I integrate Clickbank payment gateway in my wordpress project

Tags: wordpress

I want to integrate clickbank payment gateway in my wordpress project.

Please let me know how can I integrate it.

Thanks,

Anurag Srivastava

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [ClickBank API page](http://www.clickbank.com/help/account-help/account-tools/clickbank-api/) it gives you a lot of good details on where you can go. Also they have made some plugins that are already created this may or may not do what you want, if this doesnt then you need to go the API route and write your own. [ClickBank Plugins](http://www.clickbank.com/help/affiliate-help/affiliate-tools/clickbank-wordpress-plugins/)

Answer (score -1):

I have used "Seamless Clickbank" before and it works flawlessly. What bothers me is the shopping experience it offers; upon purchase, the buyer gets emailed his purchase login details that he should use to access a wordpress-admin-panel-like section where he has the product to download. I saw another alternative called "S2Member" that looks promising but I never give it a try. They offer a FREE version of their software but it doesn't support Clickbank, only paypal; yet enough to demonstrate how it works.